# Solving system of 3 equations with matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations

I am studying about Larange Multiplier on MIT OCW and I stumbled through an algebra step that I'm not quite sure about.

These are the pics from the lecture.

[The equations - pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpyMe.png)

[Matrix transformation - pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCwA9.png)

Please help me explain how he translates the system of equations into matrices form and then determine the solution. Plus, why is the determinant of matrix M in this case equals to C would give the solution?

What should I take in order to understand these concept more in depth? (I'm guessing linear algebra but I'm not too sure).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer a part of your question: look at the matrix vector multiplication and actually calculate the result:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -\lambda\\
\lambda & -2
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2x-\lambda y\\ \lambda y -2x\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$

There you find again your equations

$
2x-\lambda y = 0
$
and 
$
\lambda y -2x = 0
$

You can always bring a linear system of equations into matrix form by letting the matrix $M$ be the matrix of coefficients, i.e. $M_{i,j}$ is the coefficient in the i-th equation of the j-th variable.